# How to Open specific application using intent in android?

Tags: android

I want to open an .ics file &  i want to make sure that particular app should do that using intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For opening another app:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name.of.destination.app");
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Form there the control goes to that app, so if you wanna give some effects, you have to do it in the target app