# Custom actions using implicit intents between applications

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have been trying to get two activities in two separate applications to communicate using a custom action and an implicit intent.

The first application (server), has the following manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="edu.example.sharing.manager.SecureFileShare"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_secure_file_share" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="edu.example.sharing.action.STORE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The second application creates an intent as follows:

```
File f = new File(s);
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(fileUri);
intent.setAction("edu.example.sharing.action.STORE");               
startActivityForResult(intent, STORE_REQUEST);
```

Its manifest is normal.  When I try to send the intent in the client application, however, I get an activity not found exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {act=edu.example.sharing.action.STORE dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/Alarcon12-Rigoberto.pdf }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
```

What's causing Android to not recognize the declared activity in the second application?  Thanks.

Comment: try putting an exported attribute to the `FileStore` activity in the manifest.

Comment: also for me sometimes it dint work when i was setting the action using `setAction()`, but then i switched to using the `Intent` constructor to set the action, ex: `new Intent("edu.example,manager.action.STORE");`

Comment: Try changing your action to match your package id, so edu.example.manager.action.STORE becomes edu.example.manager.FileStore.action.STORE

Comment: I modified the code as @Varun and Dazzy_G had suggested, but it didn't solve the problem.  I have reposted the modified versions.

Answer (score 10):

After much looking, here's what I found:

When you use a **built-in** action type and attach a data field **or** when you use a **custom** action type with no data field, an `intent-filter` without a `data` element is ok.

However, when you define a custom action **and** include a data field, you must manually set the `mime-type` for the URI attached.  The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) claims that

> Normally the type is inferred from the data itself. By setting this attribute, you disable that evaluation and force an explicit type.

But that's not the case.  When I put in a `file://` URI which ended in `.txt`, Android assigned it a null `mime-type`, so it wouldn't match *any* `intent-filter`, even one with a `data` and `*/*` `mime-type`. I needed to manually set the intent's type using `setDataAndType()`.

**In short**: You *must* manually define an intent's `mime-type` when using a custom action with data.

Comment: can we use custom names in intent filter action name for e.g. <action android:name="my_intent" /> in one of our app say app1. and from app2 call it like intent I = new intent("my_intent")?

Comment: @FarazAhmad, yes we can.

Comment: For example: <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You can specify only which application to go to; you cant specify which avtivity to go to; I've already answered how to navigate to another app [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177585/how-to-open-specific-application-using-intent-in-android/12177722#12177722); after that your control goes to the other app; you have to handle it there

Comment: That's not really true. An implicit intent can map to an Activity, BroadcastReciever or Service.

Comment: I'm not trying to choose an activity to go to - I'm trying to send out an _implicit_ intent which should cause Android to choose which application(s) can handle the it.  The answer you link to refers to opening an application by name.